# Using polygons with libspatialindex

Tags: spatial-database, point-in-polygon

I am investigating using some C/C++ libraries for point-in-polygon lookups and `libspatialindex` seems popular. I've written some code that seems to do what I want but I'm not entirely sure if what I doing is correct. I have a requirement that the polygons have an arbitrary number of dimensions, they generally range from 5 to sometimes 16.

My problem is that when creating the `RTree` I have to specify the number of dimensions and so if I try to insert a polygon that has a higher number the insertion fails. Also I'm not quite sure if `SpatialIndex::Region` is the correct object to use to represent polygons, it seems to actually be a rectangle rather that what I'd call a Region as it only allows 2 dimensions.

A quick fix would be to create individual `Region`s for each pair of points in the polygon but that is quite inaccurate.

I've scoured the internet for sample code but I can't find anything worthwhile.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Finding open-source libraries which spatially index in 16 dimensions is going to be a challenge.  Unless you mean "vertices", not "dimensions".

Comment: Yes vertices is what I meant. I stuck to the vocab that libspatialindex uses as I thought it might be a standard term.

Comment: Most spatial indexes just cover the envelope of features, which reduces the complexity, but it also means you may need to do more complex comparisons with the candidates returned by indexes.

Comment: The internet seems very sparse on example code for these libraries :-/

Comment: @Richard indeed, i eventually went with boost's rtree implementation, which was both easier (somewhat) and performed better

Comment: @James, if you could post that comment along with some sample code showing how to use boost's rtree implementation, I would upvote that answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for using RTree to test polygons.

The idea is to load all of the polygons from a shape file. For simplicity, I'll only look at their exterior rings.

I then find the bounding boxes of each of the polygons and load the bounding boxes into the RTree along with a numerical id corresponding to that polygon's position in the list of loaded polygons.

Now, to see if a point is within a polygon I use the RTree to quickly determine which bounding boxes, if any, it falls into. If it falls into no box, then the point is not in a polygon. If it falls into one or more boxes, I then perform a much more expensive check to see if it actually lies within one of the polygons.

In true hacker style, I perform the more expensive check using Random Code From The Internetz. But, don't despair: I've added several links to folks explaining how the point-in-polygon check works.

I return the number of polygons the point falls into, but, obviously, you could do other things as well. Arbitrary things. Things without names.

Here's the code:

```cpp
//Compile with: g++ `gdal-config --cflags` -march=native -mtune=native  --std=c++11 -O3 -g -Wall -ffast-math -o test.exe test.cpp `gdal-config --libs` -lproj -lspatialindex_c -lspatialindex -lproj
#include <gdal/ogrsf_frmts.h>
#include <proj_api.h>
#include <spatialindex/capi/sidx_api.h>
#include <spatialindex/capi/sidx_impl.h>
#include <spatialindex/capi/sidx_config.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>

class LineString {
 public:
  std::vector<double> x;
  std::vector<double> y;
};

//Info: https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu//Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html
//Info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721406/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-inside-a-2d-convex-polygon/23223947#23223947
//Info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2922778/752843
int ContainsPoint(const std::vector<double> &vertx, const std::vector<double> &verty, const double testx, const double testy) {
  unsigned int i, j;
  int c = 0;
  for (i = 0, j = vertx.size()-1; i < vertx.size(); j = i++) {
    if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
     (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
       c = !c;
  }
  return c;
}

class Polygon {
 public:
  LineString interior;
  LineString exterior;
  double minX() const {
    return *std::min_element(exterior.x.begin(), exterior.x.end());
  }
  double maxX() const {
    return *std::max_element(exterior.x.begin(), exterior.x.end());
  }
  double minY() const {
    return *std::min_element(exterior.y.begin(), exterior.y.end());
  }
  double maxY() const {
    return *std::max_element(exterior.y.begin(), exterior.y.end());
  }
  bool containsPoint(const double testx, const double testy) const {
    return ContainsPoint(exterior.x, exterior.y, testx, testy);
  }
};

void ReadShapefile(std::string filename, std::string layername, std::vector<Polygon> &geometries){
  GDALAllRegister();
  GDALDataset *poDS;
  poDS = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpenEx(filename.c_str(), GDAL_OF_VECTOR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  if( poDS == NULL ){
    std::cerr<<"Failed to open '"<<filename<<"'!"<<std::endl;
    exit( 1 );
  }

  OGRLayer *poLayer;
  poLayer = poDS->GetLayerByName(layername.c_str());
  OGRFeature *poFeature;
  poLayer->ResetReading();
  while( (poFeature = poLayer->GetNextFeature()) != NULL ){
    /*OGRFeatureDefn *poFDefn = poLayer->GetLayerDefn();
    int iField;
    for( iField = 0; iField < poFDefn->GetFieldCount(); iField++ ){
      OGRFieldDefn *poFieldDefn = poFDefn->GetFieldDefn( iField );
      if( poFieldDefn->GetType() == OFTInteger )
          printf( "%d,", poFeature->GetFieldAsInteger( iField ) );
      else if( poFieldDefn->GetType() == OFTInteger64 )
          printf( CPL_FRMT_GIB ",", poFeature->GetFieldAsInteger64( iField ) );
      else if( poFieldDefn->GetType() == OFTReal )
          printf( "%.3f,", poFeature->GetFieldAsDouble(iField) );
      else if( poFieldDefn->GetType() == OFTString )
          printf( "%s,", poFeature->GetFieldAsString(iField) );
      else
          printf( "%s,", poFeature->GetFieldAsString(iField) );
    }*/
    OGRGeometry *poGeometry;
    poGeometry = poFeature->GetGeometryRef();
    if (poGeometry==NULL){
      //Pass
    } else if( wkbFlatten(poGeometry->getGeometryType()) == wkbPolygon ){
      OGRPolygon *poly = (OGRPolygon *) poGeometry;
      auto extring = poly->getExteriorRing();
      //Ignore interior rings for now: they're probably lakes
      geometries.emplace_back();
      for(int i=0;i<extring->getNumPoints();i++){
        geometries.back().exterior.x.emplace_back(extring->getX(i));
        geometries.back().exterior.y.emplace_back(extring->getY(i));
      }
    } else {
      std::cerr<<"Unrecognised geometry of type: "<<wkbFlatten(poGeometry->getGeometryType())<<std::endl;
    }
    OGRFeature::DestroyFeature( poFeature );
  }
  GDALClose( poDS );
}

//Saving to disk: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33395445/libspatialindex-loading-storing-index-on-disk
class SpIndex {
 private:
  Index* idx;
 public:
  SpIndex(){
    //Create a property set with default values.
    //See utility.cc for all defaults  http://libspatialindex.github.io/doxygen/Utility_8cc_source.html#l00031
    Tools::PropertySet* ps = GetDefaults();
    Tools::Variant var;

    //Set index type to R*-Tree
    var.m_varType   = Tools::VT_ULONG;
    var.m_val.ulVal = RT_RTree;
    ps->setProperty("IndexType", var);

    //Set index to store in memory (default is disk)
    var.m_varType   = Tools::VT_ULONG;
    var.m_val.ulVal = RT_Memory;
    ps->setProperty("IndexStorageType", var);

    //Initalise index
    idx = new Index(*ps);
    delete ps;

    //Check index is ok
    if (!idx->index().isIndexValid())
      throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create valid index");
  }

  void addBox(double left, double bottom, double right, double top, int64_t id){
    //Create array with lat/lon points
    double low[]  = {left,bottom};
    double high[] = {right,top};

    //Shapes can also have an object associated with them, but not this one!
    uint8_t* pData = 0;
    uint32_t nDataLength = 0;

    // create shape
    auto shape = SpatialIndex::Region(low,high,2);

    // insert into index along with the an object and an ID
    idx->index().insertData(nDataLength,pData,shape,id);
  }

  void addPolygon(const Polygon &p, int64_t id){
    double left   = p.minX();
    double bottom = p.minY();
    double right  = p.maxX();
    double top    = p.maxY();
    addBox(left,bottom,right,top, id);
  }

  std::vector<int64_t> overlaps(double x, double y) const {
    double coords[] = {x,y};

    //Object that will show us what results we've found
    ObjVisitor visitor;

    //Two-dimensional query point
    SpatialIndex::Point r(coords, 2);

    //Find those regions that intersect with the query point
    idx->index().intersectsWithQuery(r,visitor);

    //Copy results    
    std::vector<int64_t> temp;
    for(const auto &r: visitor.GetResults())
      temp.push_back(r->getIdentifier()); // dynamic_cast<SpatialIndex::IData*>(results[i]->clone()));

    //std::cout << "found " << visitor.GetResultCount() << " results." << std::endl;

    return temp;
  }

};


int CountOverlaps(const int x, const int y, const SpIndex &sp, const std::vector<Polygon> &polygons){
  auto sp_overlaps = sp.overlaps(x,y);
  //Point doesn't intersect any bounding boxes, so it can't overlap a polygon
  if(sp_overlaps.size()==0)
    return 0;

  //Within a bounding box, but is it actually within the polygon?
  int overlaps = 0;
  for(auto &pi: sp_overlaps){
    if(polygons[pi].containsPoint(x,y)){
      overlaps++;
      break;
    }
  }

  return overlaps;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  std::vector<Polygon> geometries;
  ReadShapefile("data/simplified-land-polygons-complete-3857/simplified_land_polygons.shp", "simplified_land_polygons", geometries);
  //ReadShapefile("data/land-polygons-split-3857/land_polygons.shp", "land_polygons", geometries);
  std::cerr<<"Read "<<geometries.size()<<" polygons."<<std::endl;

  SpIndex sp;

  std::cerr<<"Building index..."<<std::endl;
  for(int64_t i=0;(unsigned)i<geometries.size();i++) //TODO: Fix this unsigned int64 mess
    sp.addPolygon(geometries[i], i);
  std::cerr<<"Index built."<<std::endl;

  std::cerr<<"Number of overlaps = "<<CountOverlaps(-11501094,3771603,sp,geometries)<<std::endl;
}
```